Stay Awake in developer options turns on automatically
I turned off Stay Awake in developer options, but when ever I connect my phone to PC, running Android Studio, it turns on Stay Awake automatically, this will keep my screen on forever.
I checked everything and found it's because of Device Mirroring feature of Android Studio, but how can I disable this when I disconnect from Android Studio, automatically?
Seems this is a bug, for 2 years, not fixed:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/255272109
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/355161835

